# How do I find out if a stock certificate is worth something?

Tags: stocks

I found this Crocker National Corporation Certificate of Stock in some old papers from before 2000. Had no idea they were hidden away in a drawer. How do I find out if this paper is worth anything before i throw it away?

Comment: National in what nation? There was a US bank named Crocker, but that was merged into Wells Fargo in 1980s, so couldn't have issued stock certificates in 2000.

Comment: The stock certificate _might_ have value as a historical / collectible document.